# Как правильно пишется "33%-ный" прописью?

Tags: правописание

Правильно ли писать `тридцатитрёхпроцентные сливки`?

Comment: по моему так и пишется

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Сложные прилагательные, первая часть которых – числительное, [пишутся](http://yarus.aspu.ru/?id=101) слитно. Поэтому правильным будет написание `тридцатитрёхпроцентные`.

Answer (score -5):

Знак % указывать не нужно:

- тридцати трех процентные сливки
- 33-процентные сливки

Со знаком %:

- сливки 32%

Comment: Неправда, `тридцатитрехпроцентные` же! Сложные прилагательные, первая часть которых – числительное, пишутся слитно.

Comment: И через ё, кстати!

Comment: ребят, я русская, поэтому могу вам сказать точно, что Ё там нет :)

Comment: @Anixx Через "ё" это слово пишется только в учебных текстах по русскому языку. См. также [тут](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/is-%D1%91-a-distinct-letter-or-is-it-just-%D0%B5-with-a-diaeresis).