# What are uninfected forms and when should I use them?

Tags: морфология

I read in the Wiktionary article on [осел](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB) that it is an "uninfected" form of another word. The term "uninfected" is a Google Translate'd output for the term "неёфицированный" used in the article. I think it may be gibberish, as I couldn't find any translation or definition for it.

However, if there really are uninfected forms of words:

- Does one word, a small number of words, or a large number of words have them? In the second and third cases, what are these words and are there any rules for how the uninfected forms are formed? If there are, what are they? If there aren't, in the second case of the first question, what are the uninfected forms?
- When should I use them?

I did an online search, but couldn't find anything.

This question has been edited to make it more concise; the old version is available [here](https://orisphera.fandom.com/wiki/Uninfected_(mystery)). The answer given by Quassnoi isn't what I needed, but I've figured it out myself.

Comment: It's "uninflected" , from "inflection"

Comment: If the Wiktionary entry contained "uninfected", I think that must've been a typo because that's not a linguistic term.

Comment: When you find the source, please add it into the question and it will be considered for reopening. Thanks!

Comment: [Свекла](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0) hints at «[не]нормативное»...

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: The question is closed, but as the OP found the entry now, I just wanted to add the "resolution": it is in fact "uninfected", a bad translation of **неёфицированный**. If the _ё_ is replaced by _ин_, it would be correct. However, it simply means that it is the version of a word not containing **ё**, but **е** instead (_осел_ is the не-ё-фицированный form of _осёл_). So it means _not-ё-ified_

Comment: *неёфицированный* means "with the letter _ё_ unmarked and written as _е_". The accepted answer here seems to answer your question: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/is-%d1%91-a-distinct-letter-or-is-it-just-%d0%b5-with-a-diaeresis If it does not, please add the points which you think were left unaddressed here, or open another question. Thank you!

Comment: @Quassnoi Your last comment doesn't make any sense

Comment: @Orisphera: Russian phrase _неёфицированная форма_ (what you call "uninfected form" in your question, although infections have nothing to do with it) means "form of word with the letter _ё_ not marked with the diaeresis". Your question boils down to "when should I replace _ё_ with _е_ in my writing?". I've linked a post which I think answers this question. If you think this post does not answer your question, please specify what exactly is lacking in that answer.

Comment: @Quassnoi That's ridiculous. I've never seen the letter Ё with a diaresis.

Answer (score 2):

### Uninfected words

There is no such thing in linguistics, simple as that.

It's really easy to confuse it with "uninflected" (which is what I think did happen), but if this is indeed what you saw on Wiktionary, it was a typo, a machine translation error or something like this.

### Uninflected words

From Wikipedia:

> In linguistic morphology, an uninflected word is a word that has no morphological markers (inflection) such as affixes, ablaut, consonant gradation, etc., indicating declension or conjugation. If a word has an uninflected form, this is usually the form used as the lemma for the word.

A lemma, or a base form, is the form of the word used to list this word in dictionaries and to generally refer to the word as a set of its all possible forms.

In Russian lexicography, the singular nominative is used as a lemma for nouns, the singular nominative masculine full for adjectives, the infinitive for verbs; and these are what sometimes is called the "uninflected forms".

It doesn't strictly conform to the definition above, because the sg. nom. of, say, the word *река* does have a non-zero flexion, whereas the pl. gen. form *рек* doesn't.

Most probably, one of the words you came across on Wiktionary had been a form of the word which happened to be a homonym for the base form of another word.

This could have been something like *лис* (pl. gen. of *лиса* "female fox") which is a homonym of *лис* "male fox"; *Петь* (neo-vocative of *Петя*, a male name) and *петь* "to sing"; *пал* (past masculine singular of *пасть* "to fall") and *пал* "controlled forest fire"; and so on.

To answer your questions:

> Do one word, a small number of words, or a large number of words have them?

In the sense defined above, all words have them.

Some words don't have other forms, in which case they are usually called "invariable". There is a number of invariable words in Russian: function words like prepositions and conjunctions, adverbs, adjectival adverbs (*деепричастия*); also some borrowed nouns (*метро, пальто, радио* and so on). The percentage of invariable nouns in Russian is not big, although not tiny either, and some of them are used on the daily basis.

> When should I use them?

You use them wherever you need to use this particular form: singular nominative for nouns, and so on.

Comment: Great response, but they want the meaning of "uninfected" words, whatever on earth that means.